# Display images only after image is completely downloaded

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building ionic 3 app which displays images in pages.The problem is the app is displaying images in an ugly manner, showing partial images loading from top to bottom.

What I trying to achieve in this app is to display images only after fully downloaded preferably with a spinner.

Here is the code i used:

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <ion-title>APPNAME</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="card-background-page">
  <ion-list [virtualScroll]="categories">
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let category" class="itemcss">
      <ion-card (click)="category.golink()" class="wallcard">
          <img class='homecardimage' [src]="category.Url"/>
          <div class="card-title">{{category.Name}}</div>
        </ion-card>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
   </ion-content>
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,AlertController,LoadingController,ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
    import {HomePage} from '../home/home';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-category',
      templateUrl: 'category.html',
    })
    export class CategoryPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private network: Network,public alertCtrl: AlertController,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) 
      {}
      categories = [
  { Name: 'Popular' ,Url:'Cloudinary Link',golink:()=>this.goPopular(Cloudinary Link,Data)},
{....................................................},
{.....................................................}
      ];

goPopular(uurl,data){
.............................
}
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad CategoryPage');
        }

    }
```

I tried using different plugins to achieve this.But not working as wanted.

Is there any method to this, just using Typescript, CSS and HTML in Ionic3?

Thanks.

Comment: `collection-repeat` is an ionic v1 directive and does not exist in ionic v2+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 & collection-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834620/ionic-2-collection-repeat)

Comment: You're using **Wrong code**. I have mentioned this earlier too.See the doc http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/

Comment: I edited the question,Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `img` or `ion-img`?

Comment: I tried using ion-img but there are issues for that in Ionic Framework.So using img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `img` tag inside the `Virtual Scroll`.It [**is not recommended**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/#images-within-virtual-scroll) by the `Ionic team`.

> HTTP requests, image decoding, and image rendering can cause jank
>   while scrolling. In order to better control images, Ionic provides
>   `ion-img` to manage HTTP requests and image rendering. While scrolling
>   through items quickly, `ion-img` knows when and when not to make
>   requests, when and when not to render images, and only loads the
>   images that are viewable after scrolling

But if you have an issue with `ion-img` then you need to use [**InfiniteScroll**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/).You can bind the images to it after fetching all the images from the server.

Comment: Thanks.Will try that

Comment: You just need to bind your images after fetching it from the server to the `InfiniteScroll`. Then no issues.

Comment: Can you just give me an idea about how to use infinite scroll,i can't understand?Is there any link,video that helps in my case?I have updated typescript code to let you know what help i need.